# Ссылка для переключения между двумя языками (Django)

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Друзья, добрый день!

Есть pet-проект на Django, имеющий две локализации: на русском и английском языках.

Необходимо создать в шаблоне ссылку для переключения языков.

Пока додумался до такого решения:

```
            {% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
            {% get_available_languages as AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %}
            {% get_language_info_list for AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES as languages %}
            {% for language in languages %}
                <a href="/{{ language.code }}/">{{ language.name_local }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
```

Между тем, хотелось бы, чтобы это была *одна* ссылка, href которой варьировался бы в зависимости от актуального языка: скажем, на русскоязычной версии это была бы ссылка для перехода на англоязычную версию, и наоборот.

Буду рад, если поможете :)

**UPD (Решение)**

См. UPD в ответе E1mir.

Корневой **urls.py** в этом случае должен выглядеть так:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n")),
    # Главная страница
    path('', include('main.urls'), name='main'),
    # Контакты
    path('contact/', include('contact.urls')),

) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это довольно легко добиться, если не планируется больше 2-х языков то думаю что такое решение подойдет:

```
{% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
{% if CURRENT_LANGUAGE == "ru" %}
    <a href="/en/">English</a>
{% elif CURRENT_LANGUAGE == "en" %}
    <a href="/ru/">Русский</a>
{% endif %}
```

Помимо этого, вы можете написать отдельный контроллер для переключения языка, что сделает ваш код более гибким и обеспечит согласованность маршрутов в приложении:

```
{% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
{% if CURRENT_LANGUAGE == "ru" %}
  <a href="{% url 'switch_language' 'en' %}">English</a>
{% elif CURRENT_LANGUAGE == "en" %}
  <a href="{% url 'switch_language' 'ru' %}">Русский</a>
{% endif %}
```

Дописать urls.py:

```py
# ...

urlpatterns = [
    # ... другие маршруты ...
    path('switch_language/<str:language_code>/', views.switch_language, name='switch_language'),
]

# ...
```

**views.py** написать логику переключения языка

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.translation import activate, check_for_language, gettext as _

# ...

def switch_language(request, language_code):
    # Проверяем, что переданный язык поддерживается
    if check_for_language(language_code):
        # Активируем выбранный язык
        activate(language_code)
    else:
        # Если переданный язык не поддерживается, используем язык по умолчанию
        language_code = settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
        activate(language_code)
        
    # Перенаправляем пользователя на предыдущую страницу или на главную
    redirect_to = request.GET.get('next', '/')
    response = redirect(redirect_to)
    # Сохраняем язык в сессию (куки)
    response.set_cookie(settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME, language_code)
    return response

# ...
```

UPD:

Я забыл совсем про тот момент что у Django есть встроенный контроллер смены языка, и можно его использовать для наших целей:

Первым делом забываем что было наверху

**urls.py** добавляем нужный эндпоинт

```py
# ...

urlpatterns = [
    # ... другие маршруты ...
    path("i18n/", include("django.conf.urls.i18n")),
]

# ...
```

В темплейте делаем следующее:

```
{% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
{% if CURRENT_LANGUAGE == "ru" %}
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'set_language' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="language" value="en" />
    <button type="submit">English</button>
  </form>
{% elif CURRENT_LANGUAGE == "en" %}
  <form method="post" action="{% url 'set_language' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="language" value="ru" />
    <button type="submit">Русский</button>
  </form>
{% endif %}

<!-- Не забываем стилизовать кнопки -->
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Вы предложили просто отличную реализацию :)

Comment: Рад был помочь 

Comment: Добрый день! Насколько я понял, в новых версиях Django LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY был удалён из модуля django.utils.translation. Не подскажете, как переписать Ваш код с учётом этих нововведений?

Comment: Да вы правы, обновил ответ

Comment: Представление заработало, ссылка строится верно (127.0.0.1:8000/switch_language/en/ на русскоязычной версии, и наоборот), но переключение языка почему-то всё равно не происходит  Отдельным постом прикладываю мой актуальный код.

Comment: Увидел обновление, сейчас посмотрим

Comment: Странно, так как я сделал всё то же самое, но у меня банально простой проект, и всё работает. Язык переключается

Comment: @AlexeyPavlov Один вопрос такой, а вы добавили LocaleMiddleware в настройки Джанго? https://prnt.sc/sKqyVBLaDq0s

Comment: Да, добавил. Сейчас приложу код всех middlewares.

Comment: @AlexeyPavlov неа, этого делать не нужно, покажите лучше момент где не срабатывает перевод. И еще вопрос, вы компилировали файлы локализации? Это очень важный шаг, возможно из-за этого вам кажется что перевод не работает. Вот команда: `django-admin makemessages -a`

Comment: Ага, компилировал. Если, например, в URL 127.0.0.1:8000/ru/news/ вручную заменить "ru" на "en", то откроется страница с английской локализацией. При клике на 127.0.0.1:8000/switch_language/en/ ошибки не появляется, но и язык не меняется. Фактически просто происходит обновление страницы. Сейчас ещё приложу кусок кода шаблона.

Comment: Я нашел проблему, да, там при редиректе ошибка, вместо: `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/')` нужно было сделать это: `request.GET.get('next', '/')`. Обновил ответ. Должно теперь работать корректно

Comment: Заработало, но редиректит не на последнюю (например, 127.0.0.1:8000/ru/news/post/5/), а на главную страницу: 127.0.0.1:8000/ru/ или 127.0.0.1:8000/en/. Так и должно быть?

Comment: Да, ссылку еще подправить надо, так как мы делаем реквест, нужно next параметр отправить, я обновил ответ: `<a href="{% url 'switch_language' 'en' %}?next={{ request.path }}">English</a>`

Comment: Снова перестало работать  Теперь ссылка имеет вид 127.0.0.1:8000/switch_language/en/?next=/ru/news/post/5/, но по факту вновь просто обновляется страница.

Comment: Я обновил ответ, я залез в документацию и нашел то что реально будет работать, оказывается у джанго есть встроенный контроллер смены языка, и я думаю он подойдет.

Comment: Великолепно, всё заработало! Ещё раз огромное Вам спасибо! Сейчас дополню свой пост.